# Insert "img src" in a javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this javascript that changes the text from ABOUT to CLOSE when the ABOUT is clicked. I would love to insert an image instead of the word CLOSE.

```
    function open_fun() {
    document.getElementById('slide').innerHTML = "<a href='javascript:clo_fun()'>Close</a>";
  }
  function clo_fun() {
    document.getElementById('slide').innerHTML = "<a href='javascript:open_fun()'>About</a>";
  }
```

Is there any way I can do it?

Thanks, as always, for any help.
F.

Answer (score 1):

Similar code, just put new HTML in there:

```
function open_fun() {
  document.getElementById('slide').innerHTML = "<a href='javascript:clo_fun()'><img src='close.jpg' alt='Close'></a>";
}

function clo_fun() {
  document.getElementById('slide').innerHTML = "<a href='javascript:open_fun()'><img src='about.jpg' alt='About'></a>";
}
```

Make sure you link to the images correctly if you're in a seperate `js` folder.